# uwp StorageFile not getting a simple thumbnail

Tags: c#, image, xaml, thumbnails, uwp-xaml

I was having some trouble with databinding image thumbnail to the image on xaml so I made a minimalistic example to show you that all I am trying to get is a simple thumbnail from just one file and show it to a image element on xaml.

I've dealt with thumbnails a lot in my past uwp apps, I don't understand what I am doing wrong here.

**C# code**

```
 public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }
    protected async override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        img.Source = await GetIt();
    }
    public async Task<BitmapImage> GetIt()
    {
        var files=await KnownFolders.VideosLibrary.GetFilesAsync();
        var thumb=await files[0].GetThumbnailAsync(Windows.Storage.FileProperties.ThumbnailMode.VideosView);
        var bitm = new BitmapImage();
        bitm.SetSource(thumb);
        return bitm;
    }
}
```

**XAML CODE**

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Image Name="img"/>
</Grid>
```

**Output**  is just a blank white page

**Note** I've tried puting break point on **return bitm** and this breakpoint never executes. Also I have noticed that GetAllFiles() Method return a `System.__ComObject` where actually it should return a `IReadOnlyList<StorageFile>`.

Comment: Debug your application and watch the Output window for System.UnauthorizedAccessException

Comment: i allowed VideoLibrary from capibilities so there is no exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was just a memory problem; strange that Visual Studio didn't recognize it, I just restarted my laptop and thumbnails started to show up.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the files collection is not empty?

I have tested your code and it works for me. I had to enable VideoLibrary capability (as you did) and put a video into my Videos folder.